# Is it possible to create slanted objects in Illustrator's perspective grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, perspective

I've been looking for a while but haven't found anything useful. When working with the perspective grid, the first thing I wanted to do is to draw a laptop. I wanted its lid to be slanted at an angle. I thought I could get away with just drawing two straight lines on different planes then connecting their ends, but then I couldn't figure out how to make a perfect **round-cornered** lid. Come to think of it, how do you even draw a **foreshortened** slanted circle on the perspective grid for that matter? Anything you draw snaps onto either the vertical planes, or the horizontal planes, and there are no slanted planes to help you with that. Other tools (rotate, shear, etc.) don't seem to work. Is it possible draw slanted objects at all?

Comment: Isometric objects don't make use of the perspective grid, though. All I want is just good old perspective with all of its **foreshortening** characteristics.

Comment: Perspective grid is not suited for this task. and by the way appart for one question i dont think ive ever seen a good usecasefor the tool

Answer (score 3):

No, the tool is useless* if you want any other angle than the ones given for you. You can on the other hand do it with the rotate effect, but due to not having a way to place the pivot and depth it is also not generally useful for making 3d objects, although it is far better.

* Well I would lean on the side that the entire tool is useless.

Comment: Now that the Free Distort tool has finally been fixed and worked properly (it took years, but you've finally done it Adobe, nice f***in' job!), you can use it to draw slanted object so the Perspective Grid isn't completely useless after all.

Comment: No it is.. also you dont need slant tool perspective grid knew how to do the slant allredy in its first appearance. But the tool is useless since it can not do any useful perspective grid functions.